# How can I add 1x4 tile stairs to my octagonal gazebo model?

Tags: building, design, moc, size

How can I add 1x4 tile steps to the bottom of the front opening in the gazebo model below?   The base of the gazebo is a 10x10 octagonal plate (part 89523). I have tried using wedge and round plates but the studs on the base plate are too wide apart to fit the plates.

[image: Lego octagonal gazebo]

I want to emulate the stairs as shown here:

[image: Grant Notley park gazebo]

(Source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/kurt-b/52681755904/. Author: Kurayba. License: [CC BY-SA 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a single [jumper plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3794b), in the position shown below, rotated 45 degrees in relation to the direction of the studs of the octagonal plate. Connect plates as needed (shown below: a 4x4 plate). Add tiles on top of the plate(s) if needed.

[image: CAD diagram]